# Data extaction vs information extraction

Tags: information-retrieval

How is information extraction related to data extraction? Is it a subfield or can it be used equivalently? Data is also information. What is the relation and what are the differences?

I want to write about the general topic "data extraction". I can hardly find papers about "data extraction", but most papers deal with "web data extraction", which I want to consider separately. Maybe someone can provide me some solid papers about "data extraction".

Of course, I had a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_extraction and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_extraction but this is not a reliable source. There must be more solid information about that somewhere.

Comment: My advice would be to not worry too much about the definition of phrases like these.  These are not precisely defined terms, but rather are loose categories of work that fall into a cluster.  Focus more on learning useful technical ideas and less on looking for some crisp distinction between the two (which may not exist).

Answer (score 2):

Information gives semantics e.g. the meaning to data.  Consider pulling out of the tweets from the last hour as a raw data.    If you carry out sentiment analyses form this data you get something meaningful out of raw data: information about the mood of tweeters at the moment.

Data can be sourced by other means other than extracting.  For example apps can be developed to track information through sensors.  Imagine a sensor tracking movements in the wild, that would be raw data.  If you analyze the patterns of those movements you may infer the type of animal you have observed through the sensors e.g. information.

On a side note web extraction is possibly the most common way to extract data.
The only other common extraction scenario I can think of are ETL (Extraction and Transformation Loading) for Data-warehousing purposes using BI (Business Intelligence) tooling.